# infinite while loop rock paper scissors

Tags: python, while-loop

Ran a `while loop` in something I wanted to try so I did a quick rock paper scissors in python,

in my `while not in` statement, it keeps looping over even when I choose the correct choices, what am I doing wrong here? Also I keep getting told user and computer might be referenced before assignment

```
import random

def isWin(player,opponent):
    if (player=='p' and opponent=='r') or (player=='r' and opponent=='s') or (player=='s' and opponent=='p'):
        return True


def play_rps():
 choices=['r','p','s']
 resp='x'
 while resp.lower()!='n':
     user=input("'r' for rock, 'p' for paper 's' for scissors")
     while user not in choices:
         user = input("Wrong choice! choose  ")
         computer = random.choice(choices)

 print(f'You chose {user} and Computer chose: {computer} ')
 if computer == user:
     print('Draw!')
 elif isWin(user, computer):
     print('You win!')
 else:
     print('You lose!')
resp=input('Play again? y/n ')
  


print(play_rps())
```

Comment: It looks like the indentation of your code is not as you would intend it. Can you fix it, and make sure the indentation is not just one space, but like 4? Once space indentation is hard to read. Also, what is `resp`? Why is it a condition? Where is it changed?

Comment: I added what's missing my apologies I copied the wrong code

Answer (score 0):

Some issues:

- The question for "play again" occurs outside any loop. Moreover, the function `play_rps` returns the result of one game, so it should not attempt to loop there for multiple games. That loop should be outside the function.
- The computer variable now only gets a value when the user inputs a wrong character. This assignment should be moved outside of the inner loop.

Not an issue, but `choices` can be just a string instead of a list.

So:

```
import random

def isWin(player,opponent):
    if (player=='p' and opponent=='r') or (player=='r' and opponent=='s') or (player=='s' and opponent=='p'):
        return True

def play_rps():
    choices = "rps"  # can be just a string
    user = input("rock, paper or scissors? [rps]: ")
    while user not in choices:
        user = input("Wrong choice! choose r, p or s: ")
    computer = random.choice(choices)
    
    print(f'You chose {user} and Computer chose: {computer} ')
    if computer == user:
        return 'Draw'
    elif isWin(user, computer):
        return 'You win!'
    return 'You lose!'

def play_multiple_rps():
    resp = 'x'
    while resp.lower() != 'n':
        print(play_rps())
        resp = input('Play again? y/n ')

play_multiple_rps()
```

Finally, there is a nifty way to check for a win. If you make `choices` a global variable, you can use it to find the position of both the user's move and the opponents move. If they are in the right order, it is a win.

Here is how you can use that:

```
import random

choices = "rps"

def isWin(player,opponent):
    return opponent + player in choices + choices

def play_rps():
    user = input("rock, paper or scissors? [rps]: ")
    while user not in choices:
        user = input("Wrong choice! choose r, p or s: ")
    computer = random.choice(choices)
    
    print(f'You chose {user} and Computer chose: {computer} ')
    if computer == user:
        return 'Draw'
    elif isWin(user, computer):
        return 'You win!'
    return 'You lose!'

def play_multiple_rps():
    resp = 'x'
    while resp.lower() != 'n':
        print(play_rps())
        resp = input('Play again? y/n ')

play_multiple_rps()
```

Comment: I edited my code, my apologies can you look at it again?

Comment: Updated the answer accordingly. Please don't keep updating the code in your question, as it will make answers irrelevant.

Comment: what's wrong with choices being a list? Or is that just an alternate way of writing code

Comment: There is nothing wrong with it, @Jos -- as I wrote in my answer: "Not an issue".

Comment: One last thing, why is the while loop outside the functions? You explain that but not why, But I can see it being a better way of doing things, my only question is why so?

Comment: Because your function returns when a game is done, So even if you have a loop inside that function, the `return` is going to exit it -- that loop gets interrupted on its first iteration. Of course, you can create a second function, and put the loop there, and make it call the first function in the loop, ...etc.

Comment: I adapted the code in my answer to illustrate that the outer loop can be in a function of its own. See update.

Comment: Oh I see now, the return function already exits the program when its executed totally forgot that. I really appreciate this thank you!